# How to add randomness to the blink effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JS

```
 <script>
        (function blink() { 
            $('.demo').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(400, blink); 
        })();
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.demo {
    background: url('../res/logo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 355px;
    margin-left: 855px;
}
```

How do i add randomness to this blinking effect?

Comment: Randomness in what? You need to be more specific. The duration? The position? The easing function? And what kind of random—do the values have fall between a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as good as my answer can get until the question gets more specific:

```js
(function blink() {
  $('.demo').fadeOut(Math.random()*500).fadeIn(Math.random()*400, blink); 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="demo">I'm blinking!</span>
```

Comment: I guess this might be better received if you put it in as a snippet, so that people can see the randomness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Nice job. Exactly what i needed.
I knew i get this amount of downvotes so i didn't use my main acc)

Comment: @Scarlett Thanks! By the way, that's actually really smart. I could totally see why you did that.